# nam: child process exited abnormally

Tags: ns2, nam

Could not open GUI of network simulator using nam
[image]

Comment: Missing information  : Please edit your question to include how NAM was installed. .... Valid `nam` packages https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2 .... E.g.  `nam_1.14_amd64.deb`, which is a "one file applicaton" , no dependencies, and no ns2 required.

Comment: I installed nam with ```sudo apt install -y nam```

Comment: Well, then you can also do `sudo apt remove nam` .... and then install one of the mentioned valid packages. NAM is a GUI app, and of course it depends on X, i.e. you must have a window manager / a desktop environment installed.  Editing your question : That's the *Edit* button in your question : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71880790/edit